# When using ASP.NET MVC and LINQ, should you be creating stored procedures in your SQL database?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, stored-procedures, database-design

This is something I don't understand. The conventional wisdom for stored procedures is to always create them if you know know a query that will be executed as part of your application and can describe it in terms of paramaters (which is like 99.9999% of the time .. the other 0.0001% being if you create an application in which queries are unpredictible because the user is writing queries or something). But if I do that -- set up triggers, cascade deletes, sprocs for everything -- when I create my database, then what is the point of even having a model? The only purpose the model serves in that case is to tell the database "Go!" and the database performs all the logic. Makes the M in MVC very irrelevant.

Sorry if this seems like an opinion-based quesiton, but I feel like I'm not really getting the gist of ASP.NET MVC if on one hand I'm being told "Make the database handle as much logic as possible" and the other hand have these tools like LINQ, Entity, etc., that are all for creating a C# way of querying the database.

Are ASP.NET MVC and stored procedures antonyms?

Comment: 4 people have voted for this question to be closed with the reason "Unclear what you're asking". Well, if there could be a reason for this question to be closed, I would say being primarily opinion-based would be a better option, but even that doesn't seem like a good reason to me. The fact that you can use stored procedures in your MVC applications is not opinion-based, if you think you should not use them, then you don't know anything about MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, ASP.NET MVC and stored procedures are not antonymous. They are just not related. But that does not mean they cannot both be in the same application.

I'd like to think of MVC as a design pattern for presentation/UI. The M in the MVC is the entity you'd like to represent. It can be a simple login model with holds the username and password, or a larger model that represents a social media user, with status updates, list of friends and their status updates. For very small apps, the model could match exactly as your datasets; in which case, your model can be your datasets. But in larger apps, your model could represent the business objects, which often do not exactly correspond with the underlying datasets.

A lot of ASP.NET MVC examples are small apps which use the datasets as the models. But this is not often a good design to use on larger applications where you want to de-couple the database from your presentation layer. In such case, the model could be the business objects, and they would sit on your business logic layer which may be different from your data access layer. In which case, the model is not aware of your database, nor is it aware of whether you use stored procedures or LINQ for your queries.

It is also possible that an ASP.NET MVC application retrieves and updates data through another application's API. In which case, the MVC application's model would be the data that the API returns or accepts. The API handles the model retrieval and persistence.

So the M in MVC can be not just the datasets in a database.

As for queries, yes it is a good practise to run as much of your queries on your data server because your data server is designed for that. And you can make your data server return only the data that your application needs. You can achieve this either by using stored procedures or LINQ. I have preference on using LINQ over stored procedures. I would avoid stored procedures if I can. But that's my preference. It is also my preference to not put any business logic on a stored procedure.